# Echoing specific amount of records

Tags: php

]How would I be able to show more records on the click of a link?

For example I have 200 records in my tables and want to echo 30 of them. And with the click of button/link echo 50 instead of 30.

I use this code to echo 30 of them at the moment.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost","uname", "upass", "db_name") or 
                   die('could not connect: '. mysqli_connect_error());

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_aanbiedingen LIMIT 30";
       $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

               echo "<div id=aanbieding> <img class='productimage' src='".$row['image']."'> <p class='prijs'>" . $row['prijs'] . "</p> <p class='descriptie'>" . $row['product'] . "</p><img class='blogo' src='images/".$row['winkel']."'></div>";  
               }
```

What if I want to increase that to 50?

I could of course copy the page increase limit to 50 and link to that but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Accept `limit` as a query string parameter. Validate and sanitize it, and use it in your query.

Comment: Are you wanting to refresh the whole page, or do it via AJAX?

Comment: @JonathanM I am not familiar with AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, replace your code with:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost","uname", "upass", "db_name") or 
                   die('could not connect: '. mysqli_connect_error());
if(isset($_GET['limit'])){$limit = intval($_GET['limit']);}
else{$limit = 30;}
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_aanbiedingen LIMIT ".$limit;
       $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

               echo "<div id=aanbieding> <img class='productimage' src='".$row['image']."'> <p class='prijs'>" . $row['prijs'] . "</p> <p class='descriptie'>" . $row['product'] . "</p><img class='blogo' src='images/".$row['winkel']."'></div>";
```

Then, use one of these solutions:

### Method 1- using HTML only

(*Less code required, no need to load libraries, but the page will need to be refreshed.*)

Use this code for your button:

```
<button><a href="yourphppage.php?limit=50">View more</a></button>
```

### Method 2- Using jquery

(*Little more code required, jquery library needed, no refresh. I'd personally choose this solution.*)

1)Put in the `<head>` section of the page this code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function openLink(url){
$("#more").html("Loading...");
$("#more").load(url, function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
   if (textStatus == "error") {
      $("#princ").html('An error occurred! Please try again.');
   }
});
}
</script>
```

2)Then, use this code for your button:

```
    <button><a href="yourphppage.php?limit=50" onclick="return:false; javascript:openLink('yourphppage.php?limit=50');">View more</a></button>
<div id="more"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much does exactly what i wanted  :)!

Comment: I am trying to it says i have to wait a minute ;)

Comment: Causes more server overhead. I always see these questions where someone picks the worst answer and the solution and it's because an answerer is afraid to lose points and bullies the asker into committing. @Angelo Answer more questions and you'll get the points. Let people take their time because more often than not a better solution will present itself and you may learn something new.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ you're right, sorry, I don't really want to "bully" (as you defined my behaviour) anyone. You're right about the two requests, thought that doing one more query selecting 30 more records wouldn't have affected so much server performance.

Comment: @Maantje feel free to un-accept my answer if you believe the one of AbsoluteƵERØ is better, I didn't really want to force you :)

Comment: I wont un-accept your answer because i all ready accepted it. It would be nice to be able accept multiple answers as answers since there usually multiple possible answer to the same exact question. absolutezero's answer looks good aswell ill try them both and see wich one ill use :) but anyway thanks to both of you for helping me out ^^

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making 2 calls, put the first 30 in one wrapper `div`. Put the second 20 in another wrapper `div`. When someone changes it from 30 to 50, then turn on the second `div`. It's less processing, server connections, and coding. Keep it simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript Example</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateDisplay(val) {
        var dNum = val;
        if(dNum == 50){
          document.getElementById("wrapper2").style.display="block";
          alert(dNum);
        } else {
          document.getElementById("wrapper2").style.display="none";
          alert(dNum);
        }

    }
    </script>


    <select name="limit" onChange="updateDisplay(this.value)">
       <option value="30">Show 30</option>
       <option value="50">Show 50</option>
    </select>

    <div id="wrapper1">
     First 30 go here.
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper2" style="display:none;">
     Next 20 go here.
    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```